# Regular expression to match text after 3 character from string

Tags: regex

I have a string like

```
January
February
March
```

I want a regex which matches only uary(January), ruary(February) and ch(march) i.e string after 3 character

I have tried this `[a-zA-Z]{1,3}(.*?)$`
Its working but giving match in group. I don't want in group. I want pure match

Comment: Please provide language tag, what regex flavor?

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is actually the kind of thing that would be used for this (`$` aside), and the "uary" and what not would be called with $1.

`(?<=[a-zA-Z]{3}).*(?=\s|$)` will do in non-javascript languages, without any capture groups.

https://regex101.com/r/iV0tR3/1

Answer (score 1):

Use lookbehind.

```
(?<=^[a-zA-Z]{3}).*
```

or `\K`

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}\K.*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
\b\w{3}
```

`\b` is word boundary, then 3 alphanumerics (plus any underscore).

Here'a a demo: https://regex101.com/r/dX8eC7/1

Comment: OP does not want to match the first three characters.

Comment: intention to my understanding was to substitute out the first 3 characters, leaving just the remaining letters - i.e., s/\b\w{3}//g